# RegEx for substituting only to the left of LaTeX comments

Tags: regex, perl, latex, comments, tex

The file that I am transforming (LaTeX) contains comments, which lie to the right of a %. Any non-escaped percent sign marks a comment.

Using perl, I want to perform regex substitutions, say

```perl
s/dog/CAT/g
```

but only in non-commented text. Thus the lines

> One dog ate a rat but 5\% of dogs ate the apple % dog??
>
> My dog is smarter than your honor student

would be transformed to

> One CAT ate a rat but 5\% of CATs ate the apple % dog??
>
> My CAT is smarter than your honor student

Here, of course, is how to match a non-escaped percent sign:

```
bash: cat aaa
dog % cat
dog \% cat
bash: cat aaa | perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; print if (m/(?<!\x5c)%/)'
dog % cat
bash:
```

This must be a well-known question but I did not find the right search terms to find the answer. Can one not do this in perl with a single regex? Obviously, my substitution regex would substitute **every** `dog` with `CAT`, even in comments.

Answer (score 1):

One way: Extract all text up to (unescaped) `%` then run replacement in that

```
s/ (.*?) ([^\\]%.*) /$r=$2; $1=~s{dog}{CAT}gr . $r/egx;
```

The `/e` modifier makes the replacement side be evaluated as code, and we run a regex in it.

There we need to first save away the "rest" of the line (after `%`), captured in `$2`, since `$2` will get cleared in the coming regex.

The modifier `/r` in that regex makes it return the transformed string, convenient for forming the value to be used as the replacement (by concatenating it with the rest of the line).  Also, having the original unchanged under `/r` allows us to use substitution on `$1` (which is read-only).

---

The `[^\\]` above requires a character other than `\` to precede `%`, for the comment to start. However, as it requries a character it makes the whole regex match if the line starts with `%` *and* has further unescaped `%`, which is wrong.  This is quite possible: a line has some commented text (`%...`), and at some point also gets commented out altogether.

If this is indeed a concern use a negative lookahead instead

```
s{ (.*?) ((?<!\\)%.*)? $ }{ $r=($2//''); $1=~s{dog}{CAT}gr . $r}egx;
```

Note that the (necessary) backtracking in this hurts efficiency.  That should not be a problem for an occasional Latex file, but if it is done *a lot* it may be. In this case parse each line properly, whereby lookarounds won't be needed.

Test, with input file `data.txt`

```
One dog 5\% of dogs % dog
%dog more than 10\% of % dogs
dogs \% and dogs
```

The one-liner

```
perl -nwe'
    s{ (.*?) ((?<!\\)%.*)? $}{$r=($2//""); $1=~s{dog}{CAT}gr . $r}egx; print
' data.txt
```

prints

```
One CAT 5\% of CATs % dog
%dog more than 10\% of % dogs
CATs \% and CATs
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler to break it into two tasks: find the part of the string that isn't a comment, and then do your substitution on that part. Here's one approach for that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = 'One dog ate a rat but 5\% of dogs ate the apple % dog??';
if (my ($first, $second) = $str =~ m/\A(.*?)((?<!\\)%.*)?\z/s) {
  $first =~ s/dog/CAT/g;
  $str = defined $second ? "$first$second" : $first;
}
```

This uses a [negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) to find the first unescaped percent sign, even if it's the first character of the string, and makes the comment half optional so it will still substitute if there's no comment. However it will still involve a lot of [backtracking](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Backtracking) so if performance is a concern a more extensive implementation may be preferable.

EDIT: The reason that this seems so complex is that you're trying to do something regex isn't really great at. You want to find things in a string based on contextual state. The "better" way to do this is to parse the string into tokens, which is generally done with a loop that keeps state and a regex (which is good at this part); even if it's just tokens of "non-comment string", "comment start", "comment string". Then you can easily operate on only the non-comment strings.

Here's how an expanded algorithm might look, I tried to simplify it to the amount of parsing needed for this case and it could certainly be golfed further. The key is to use `m/\G.../g` to incrementally parse the string (`\G` anchors the match to the end of the last match with the `/g` modifier in scalar context), and rely on the regex engine picking the first alternation option that matches that point in the string. This way you go through the string sequentially with no backtracking, and keep the state outside the loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = 'One dog ate a rat but 5\% of dogs ate the apple % dog??';
my $in_comment;
my ($text, $comment) = ('','');
while ($str =~ m/\G(((?<!\\)%)|%|[^%]+)/g) {
  my ($token, $start_comment) = ($1, $2);
  $in_comment = 1 if defined $start_comment;
  if ($in_comment) {
    $comment .= $token;
  } else {
    $text .= $token;
  }
}
$text =~ s/dog/CAT/g;
$str = "$text$comment";
```

Here's a different tokenizing approach that allows you to handle escaped backslashes, if this is allowed, by keeping track of whether the next token is being escaped:

```
my $escaping;
while ($str =~ m/\G((\\+)|(%)|[^\\%]+)/g) {
  my ($token, $backslashes, $percent) = ($1, $2, $3);
  $in_comment = 1 if defined $percent and !$escaping;
  $escaping = (defined $backslashes and length($backslashes) % 2) ? 1 : 0;
```

[Parser::MGC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC) is an abstraction of this concept to an object interface.

(Also: this method will not always be faster than a single backtracking regex, especially with simpler parsing and shorter lines.)

Comment: Could you give an example of the better way, parsing the string into tokens? And could it be written as a perl script that operates on a file? With the default input record separator, it would work on one line at a time, and of course there would be no hard-coded definition of `$str` inside the code.

Comment: @JacobWegelin I added an example. This concept probably won't map well to a one liner but it could certainly be used in a perl script as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

A more prolix and detailed solution, building on zdim's:

```
bash: cat aaa
dog and dogs and many many dogs% dog
dog and dogs and many many dogs\% dog
bash: cat aaa | perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $r; s/ (.*?) ((?<!\x5c)%.*) /$r=$2; $1=~s{dog}{CAT}gr . $r/egx; print;'
CAT and CATs and many many CATs% dog
dog and dogs and many many dogs\% dog
```

Note this allows a comment marker immediately after non-comment text; it does not require a space to precede the %.

Comment: (1) "_it does not require a space to precede the `%`_" -- if that refers to the quoted answer (mine) then note that in my answer no space is required. The space that was there was not a part of the pattern but for readability, by `/x` (also removed now). (2) This doesn't work -- no replacements on the second line?

Comment: (the lookarounds can be tricky. see my updated answer as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Default input record separator: one line at a time.
# Read through a LaTeX file line by line. Distinguish comment from text.
# Parse each line into exactly 2 tokens. 
# Boundary between tokens is the first non-escaped %.
# $text: everything up to, but excluding, boundary if exists; else entire line.
# $comment: possibly null, from the first non-escaped % to end of line. 
# Last (pathological) line might not end in LF, hence LF is excluded from tokens and appended at the end.
# Consequently, output will end in LF whether input did or not.
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.18.2;
my $text;
my $comment;
while (<>) {
    # Non-greedy: match until first non-escaped %
    # Without final ([\n]?), pathological last line would not match and an entire last line of comment would be mistaken for text.
    if (m/(^.*?)((?<!\x5c)%.*)([\n]?)/) {
        $text=$1;
        $comment="$2";
    }
    else {
        s/\n//g; # There can be at most one LF, at the end; remove it if it exists.
        $text=$_;
        $comment="";
    }
    # Here, 
    # (1) examine $text for LaTeX-illegal characters; if found, exit with informative error
    # (2) identify LaTeX environments such as \verbatim and \verb, which are to be left alone
    # (3) perform any desired global changes on remaining text
    $text=~s/dog/CAT/g;
    # Add LF back in which we explicitly removed above 
    print "$text$comment\n";
}
```